# Can some weapons not fuse with each other?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

Can some weapons not fuse with each other? Because when I tried to fuse the Aurum Club and the Palutena Bow it didn't work and this also happened with the Doom Cannon and the EZ Cannon. And I'm pretty sure I have all the weapons. And also I'm asking if these specific weapons can fuse. Not why they can't. And tell me what they fuse into if they can.

Comment: I've changed it so that at the bottom it explains why it's not a duplicate. And plz don't hate on me I'm just a beginner at this.

Comment: This question has been closed. If you would like it to be reopened, you could appeal or ask for a discussion about this question at [meta].